# Stopping Intellisense from outputting Assembly directive by default

Tags: intellisense, ascx

I'm using ASCX files quite extensively in my latest project and I've come across an annoyance - when I go to type:

```
<%= Something %>
```

Due to Intellisense I get the following when I type the equals sign:

```
<%@ Assembly= %>
```

This happens anywhere in the file, which is strange as the top of the file is the only place I would ever want such a directive.  The only way to stop it is to type `<%` and then hit escape, then type the equals sign.

Is there a way to prevent this default behaviour, and possibly change it to `<%= %>`?

Comment: Further to this I've noticed that it only happens when I'm typing at the root level, but if I'm inside a DIV it just works.  I guess this is a sort-of workaround but it would still be nice to see if there's a better way.

Comment: This is _THE_ most irritating bug in Visual Studio. I hope someone knows how to turn this off...